# Jest testing react component with react-intersection-observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, intersection-observer

I'm trying to test a component that has a child component that includes react-intersection-observer but I always get an error

I tried to import the library but it still fails.
This the initial test

```
    beforeEach(() => {
      testContainer = document.createElement("div");
      document.body.appendChild(testContainer);
      subject = memoize(() =>
        mount(<FilterNav {...props} />, { attachTo: testContainer })
      );
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      testContainer.remove();
    });

    context("the main filter is shown initially", () => {
      it("sets focus on the primary filter", () => {
        subject();
        const input = testContainer.querySelector(".main-input");
        expect(document.activeElement).toEqual(input);
      });
```

I'm getting this error -> Uncaught [ReferenceError: IntersectionObserver is not defined]

Is there a way I can mock IntersectionObserver?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually was able to solve this issue with a mock function and include it in the window object

```
const observe = jest.fn();

window.IntersectionObserver = jest.fn(function() {
  this.observe = observe;
});
```

Answer (score 34):

you can do something like this in mock file(i called it intersectionObserverMock.js for exmple):

```
const intersectionObserverMock = () => ({
     observe: () => null
})
window.IntersectionObserver = jest.fn().mockImplementation(intersectionObserverMock);
```

and in the test file import the file directly like this:

```
import '../__mocks__/intersectionObserverMock';
```

this will solve youre "IntersectionObserver is not defined" issue

Comment: This worked for me in combination with declaring an Window interface like this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16255#issuecomment-436935103

declare global {
  interface Window {
    IntersectionObserver: typeof IntersectionObserver
  }
}

Comment: Minor addition to this is to also add other functions that you are using on observer. In my case I had to add `disconnect: () => null` because I used `observer.disconnect()` in my code

Answer (score 21):

Having same issue with Component that using IntersectionObserver.

Update: we need to import intersection-observer directly on test file.

`import 'intersection-observer';`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. `npm i --save-dev intersection-observer`

Answer (score 15):

The only thing that worked for me, create a file `src\__mocks__\intersectionObserverMock.js`

```
global.IntersectionObserver = class IntersectionObserver {
  constructor() {}

  observe() {
    return null;
  }

  disconnect() {
    return null;
  };

  unobserve() {
    return null;
  }
};
```

In your test import file:

```
import './__mocks__/intersectionObserverMock'
```

Answer (score 14):

Create a mock in your setupTests file:

```
// Mock IntersectionObserver
class IntersectionObserver {
  observe = jest.fn()
  disconnect = jest.fn()
  unobserve = jest.fn()
}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'IntersectionObserver', {
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  value: IntersectionObserver,
})

Object.defineProperty(global, 'IntersectionObserver', {
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  value: IntersectionObserver,
})
```

This will sort it not being defined.

Comment: This worked great, thank you! :) I had to add `disconnect` for my use case, edited answer to add it.

Answer (score 6):

To fix this issue I'd recommend using `mockAllIsIntersecting` from [test-utils.js](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer#testing) in `react-intersection-observer`. This function mocks the IntersectionObserver.

e.g.

```
import { mockAllIsIntersecting } from 'react-intersection-observer/test-utils';

it("sets focus on the primary filter", () => {
    subject();
    mockAllIsIntersecting(true);

    const input = testContainer.querySelector(".main-input");
    expect(document.activeElement).toEqual(input);
  });
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! No need to mock IntersectionObserver yourself. The test-utils already does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I extended Teebu's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493088/5404186) to trigger a first intersecting element. My test then act as if the intersection would match.

```
global.IntersectionObserver = class IntersectionObserver {

  constructor(private func, private options) {}

  observe(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.func([{isIntersecting: true, target: element}]);
  }

  disconnect() {
    return null;
  };

  unobserve() {
    return null;
  }
};
```