# Why does a react component, tested with React Testing Library has issue with react-intersection-observer?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-intersection-observer

I wrote a component built with `react` 17.0.2 that uses `react-intersection-observer` 9.1.0

```
  import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer'

  ...

  const [ref, inView] = useInView({
    threshold: 0.99,
    root: scrollRef.current,
    delay: 250,
    trackVisibility: true,
    onChange: (inView: boolean) => {
      onChildInView(index, inView)
    }
  })
```

to detect sliding behaviours inside or outside the viewport. And the component works fine.

I wrote some unit tests to make the component safer, using `@testing-library/react` 12.1.4 and `@testing-library/jest-dom` 5.16.3.

As soon as I test just the existence or visibility of the above component with the following code

```
  describe('method render', () => {
    test('renders correctly', () => {
      render(
        <MyComponent
          props={...}
          data-testid="component-id"
        >
          <div />
          <div />
        </MyComponent>
      )

      const componentNode = screen.getByTestId('component-id')

      expect(componentNode).toBeInTheDocument()
      expect(componentNode).toBeVisible()
    })
  })
```

the testing library complains with the message error.

```
    ReferenceError: IntersectionObserver is not defined
```

I tried to fix it with this suggestion of mocking the library (as linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008341/jest-testing-react-component-with-react-intersection-observer)) written at the top of the test

```
  const intersectionObserverMock = () => ({
    observe: () => null
  })

  declare global {
    interface Window {
      IntersectionObserver: typeof IntersectionObserver
    }
  }

  window.IntersectionObserver = jest.fn().mockImplementation(intersectionObserverMock);
```

but it did not work due to

```
  TypeError: observer.unobserve is not a function
```

Suggestions? Missing something?

Comment: Have you tried using `mockAllIsIntersectiong` from the `test-utils.js` https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer#testing

Comment: this indeed fixes it, thanks

Comment: Thats great news. I'll add it as an answer

Comment: If you are using nextjs or a framework with SSR, that may be your problem. Intersection observer is a browser API, and wouldn't be available during SSR. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9805

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this issue I'd recommend using `mockAllIsIntersecting` from [test-utils.js](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer#testing) in `react-intersection-observer`. This function mocks the IntersectionObserver.

e.g.

```
import { mockAllIsIntersecting } from 'react-intersection-observer/test-utils';   

describe('method render', () => {
    test('renders correctly', () => {
      render(
        <MyComponent
          props={...}
          data-testid="component-id"
        >
          <div />
          <div />
        </MyComponent>
      )

      mockAllIsIntersecting(true)

      const componentNode = screen.getByTestId('component-id')

      expect(componentNode).toBeInTheDocument()
      expect(componentNode).toBeVisible()
    })
  })
```

Comment: Hey, it's helped me to fix my problem but I would like to know why ? cause in other tests I got the same use case and I don't need to mock insertion :/