# React 18 Jest Test issue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm getting an error after upgrading to React 18. Don't really understand what this means tbh and wasn't getting it before!

And I don't use IntersectionObserver in my codebase

The tests failing have a 3rd party component that uses IntersectionObserver

```
ReferenceError: IntersectionObserver is not defined

  4 |
  5 | test('should render appeals manager successfully ', () => {
> 6 |   const { baseElement } = render(<AppealComponent appeal={Appeals[0]} />);
    |                           ^
  7 |   expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
  8 | });
  9 |

  at createObserver (../../node_modules/src/observe.ts:66:22)
  at observe (../../node_modules/src/observe.ts:139:38)
  at InView.observeNode (../../node_modules/src/InView.tsx:118:25)
  at InView._this.handleNode (../../node_modules/src/InView.tsx:153:10)
  at commitAttachRef (../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23453:18)
  at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23315:9)
```

Comment: sure its react fault ?,  does your codebase uses `IntersectionObserver` ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59176608/18532711) answer your question?

Comment: my codebase doesn't use IntersectionObserver